# json object composition details

Tags: json, syntax, data-structures

in .json text, is the 'value' in a basic single pair object the title of a value type (e.g. [string, number, object]), or a value for a typed object (e.g. 2, or "dog", or Object3)?

This is how http://www.json.org/ presents the information:

> "An object is an unordered set of
>   name/value pairs. An object begins
>   with { (left brace) and ends with }
>   (right brace). Each name is followed
>   by : (colon) and the name/value pairs
>   are separated by , (comma)."

[image]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://www.json.org/object.gif))</sub>

> 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value.

As an example, the following:

```
{ "foo": "bar" }
```

Has a name of 'foo' and a value of 'bar'.

Comment: Close, but not JSON. This is: `{ "foo": "bar" }`